# Angular/Typescript : add/update HTML after an HTTP response is received

Tags: javascript, html, json, angular, typescript

I have a function in typescript were i make an HTTP request, the request is supposed to receive a json as a response with data that I want to display on my HTML as soon as I receive the json response. 
Example code:

Typescript:

```js
this._httpProblemsService.submitVerifierTool(codeObject).subscribe(
            data => {
                if(data["status_server"] == "successful run" &&     data["status_student"] == "successful run"){
                    this.professorOutputTestCase = data["output_server"];
                    this.outputStudent = data["output_student"];
                }
                document.getElementById("outputStudent").innerHTML = this.outputStudent;
                document.getElementById("outputServer").innerHTML = this.professorOutputTestCase;
            }
        );
```

Here's the HTML:

```
<!-- Verifier Tool tab -->
<tab-static tabTitle="Verifier Tool" boldTitle=true>
     <h4><b>Verifier Tool</b></h4>
         <div>Try here your test cases before submission</div>
               <span>
                     <h4><b>Your Input:</b></h4>
                     <input placeholder="Your professor's input sample{{professorInputTestCase}}" id="student_input" type="text" class="form-control">
                     <h4><b>Expected Output:</b></h4>
                     <pre id="outputServer" class="white-space"> {{professorOutputTestCase}}</pre>
                     <h4><b>Your Output:</b></h4>
                     <pre id="outputStudent" class="white-space">{{outputStudent}}</pre>
                     <button type="button" class="btn btn-success"
                             (click)="verifierToolSubmitReceived()">Submit
                     </button>
              </span>
</tab-static>
```

I know that: `document.getElementById("outputStudent").innerHTML = this.outputStudent;` 
is a javaScript implementation but what can be the equivalent of doing this with TypeScript/Angular?

Comment: You are saving your response to a variable and then using the variable in the HTML (the {{outputStudent}}). This should be enough. The old Javascript getElementById shouldn't be needed.

Comment: Have you walked through any Angular tutorials? This is covered in the basics. https://angular.io/tutorial

Comment: @Steve Thanks I had a problem with my server and it wasn't running with the updated code, that's why it didn't worked, I just took away the getElementById and worked, many thanks tho!